# Turning numpy array into boolean array indicating max of subarray

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a matrix A of dimension (N*J) x M where each column consists of $N$ subvectors of length J. Now for each of these subvectors I want to find the position of the max and then generate a matrix B of the same dimension which is 1 whenever the corresponding element in A is a max of the corresponding subvector. Assume the max for each subvector is unique (values are drawn from continuous random variables).

Simple example (with N=2, J=2, M=2):

```
A = 
[1, 0;
 2, 4;
 9, 3;
 7, 8]

B = 
[0, 0;
 1, 1;
 1, 0;
 0, 1]
```

Any help appreciated, thank you!

I have no good start on it, my first guesses where using a combination of np.split into the subvectors, then taking the argmax, and casting everything back into a Boolean array.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, converting the shape of the original to and from a `(J, N*M)`-shaped array:

```
import numpy as np

J = 2  # size of each subvector
A = np.array([[1, 0], [2, 4], [9, 3], [7, 8]])

# Make an array where each column is a length-J subvector
# order='F' means we fill column by column
subvecs = np.reshape(A, (J, -1), order='F')

# Flag elements equal to subvector max as 1, else 0
maxes = np.max(subvecs, axis=0)
is_max = np.equal(subvecs, maxes).astype(int)

# Reshape back to the original array
B = np.reshape(is_max, A.shape, order='F')
print(B)
```

giving:

```
[[0 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]]
```